# How to convert string which has multiple object like structure into JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I need to convert below **string** to JavaScript object

```
const str = `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]`
```

I am looking for object like

```
[[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]]
```

I have tried below code

```
const regex = /(\n)/gm;
const str = `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]`;
const subst = `,`;

let result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
JSON.parse(result)
```

getting below output

```
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]
```

JSON.Parse() gives below error

```
JSON.parse(result)
undefined:1
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]
                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 21
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\regextest.js:11:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: this is an invalid string cannot be parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]`
console.log(str.split("\n").map(JSON.parse))
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert string in to object use JSON.parse method:

```
JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using **JSON.parse** method you can convert this but you have to pass a valid string into this

```js
var str = '[[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}],[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]]';
console.log(str);
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, here is the code

```
const regex = /(\n)/gm;
const str = `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]`;
const subst = `;`

let result = str.replace(regex, subst);

result = result.split(';')
let data = []
result.forEach(item => {
  if (item.length > 0) {
    data.push(JSON.parse(item))
  }
})
console.log(data);
```

Output

```
[ [ { a: 'b' }, { c: 'd' } ], [ { a: 'b' }, { c: 'd' } ] ]
```